# how to pass data from one array list to another array list

Tags: java

I have an array list of:

```
ArrayList<ItemsBean> itemsList1 = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();
```

I called the data from data base and added to this `Arraylist`

```
while (items.next()) {
    ItemsBean bean = new ItemsBean();
    bean.setInvNo(items.getString("Invoice_Number"));
    bean.setItemnNameDisplay(items.getString("Prodname"));
    bean.setParentobjectid(items.getString("ParentObjectID"));

    bean.setQuantityDisplay(items.getInt("Quantity"));
    bean.setProdnum(items.getInt("ProdNum"));

    itemsList1.add(bean);
}
```

Now I have new array list:

```
ArrayList<ItemsBean> newListitems2 = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();
```

now I want to pass same data to this new array list in same activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `addAll()` or try like this `arraylist2 = arraylist1` .

`addAll()` is like below

```
arraylist2.addAll(arraylist1);
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList newListitems2 = new ArrayList(itemsList1);
ArrayList has constructor, receiving Iterable<> as argument, so you cancreate new list with values from another list. Notice, values will remain the same, ArrayList only contains references to actual objects.

Comment: @joy how is it "no use"? This answer appears to me to be the correct answer. (Possibly with a necessary correction: `ArrayList<ItemsBean> newListitems2 = new ArrayList<>(itemsList1)`.)